# Set Different Navation bar title for different View controller in iphone

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, title

I have navigation bar i am setting title on image which is used in navigation bar it works fine but when i use same code for other controller it shows same previous title on navigation bar not the new one.

here is the code

```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView]; 




titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,2,250,36)];
titleLabel.text=@"Activity";
titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size :18];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleLabel];
```